# Error when trying to upload object to S3 through Lambda with AWS SDK, InvalidAccessPointARN: Access point ARN region is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload a txt to S3.
The lambda function has the following policies:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

And this is the code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const bucketName = 'arn:aws:s3:::0dd839423855435';
  const keyName = 'test.txt';
  const content = 'Test';

  const params = {
    'Bucket': bucketName,
    'Key': keyName,
    'Body': content
  };

  try {
    const data = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

And this the error

```
InvalidAccessPointARN: Access point ARN region is empty
    at Request.validateAccessPointArn (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:201:28)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at Request.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:403:15)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:792:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Request.promise (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:778:12) {
  code: 'InvalidAccessPointARN',
  time: 2020-06-29T23:00:43.979Z
```

I don't know what I am doing bad. Also, I would like to avoid creating an access point.

Comment: S3 access points require region in their ARN as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-access-points.html).

Comment: Your answer is there please approve it if it is helping. so others can also have benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing I guess you are using terraform or something like **Infrastructure as Code**.

That's why your bucket name is the randomly generated number: **0dd839423855435**

So you do not have to use **arn** (arn:aws:s3:::0dd839423855435) as bucket name, instead of using arn use just and just only bucket name or in other words this is the **id** of the bucket which is this **0dd839423855435** in your case.

Lambda and S3 should be located in same region.

In case you created s3 with terraform then you can output the arn or id by doing this:

For ARN:

```
output "your-bucket-arn" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.your-bucket.arn
}
```

For ID:

```
output "your-bucket-id" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.your-bucket.id
}
```

Comment: @Ben thanks. can you please accept my answer as a solution.